# Recursion query in Postgres (mutual match based on score)

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I got records from two different sources and the goal is to create link between sources that match each other. For that purpose there is applied trained AI model which assigns score of probability of match for each record from source A to each record to source B. The table `score` then looks like this.

```
src_a_id    src_b_id    score
-----------------------------
1           foo         0.8
1           bar         0.7
1           baz         0.6
2           foo         0.9
2           bar         0.5
2           baz         0.3
```

Now I need to read from this table what is the most likely counter match to `src_a` record with id `1`. When you select data with sql `SELECT * FROM score WHERE src_a_id = 1 ORDER BY score DESC;` you will get this result.

```
src_a_id    src_b_id    score
-----------------------------
1           foo         0.8
1           bar         0.7
1           baz         0.6
```

Here it looks like the first row is result I am looking for and so the counter match is `src_b` record with id `foo` with mutual score `0.8` but it is not correct. We can query from the other side to verify result. What is counter match to `src_b` with id `foo`? Using sql `SELECT * FROM score WHERE src_b_id = 'foo' ORDER BY score DESC;` we get result:

```
src_a_id    src_b_id    score
-----------------------------
2           foo         0.9
1           foo         0.8
```

From the first query it has looked like `src_a` id `1` matches `src_b` id `foo`.
From the second query it is clear that previous conclusion is wrong because `src_b` id `foo` matches to `src_a` id `2` because this pair has higher mutual score.

How should I write query to find the match to `src_a` record with id `1` considering that table will have thousands hundred records?

My first steps were searching for some recursive queries in Postgres but tutorials I have found didn't fit to my use case and honestly I am quite failing make up any working application so far.

### EDIT

For the demonstration syntax of the creating testing data:

```
CREATE TABLE score (
    src_a_id integer NOT NULL,
    src_b_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    score decimal(3,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO score (src_a_id, src_b_id, score)
VALUES 
    (1, 'foo', 0.8),
    (1, 'bar', 0.7),
    (1, 'baz', 0.6),
    (2, 'foo', 0.9),
    (2, 'bar', 0.5),    
    (2, 'baz', 0.3);
```

From the testing data it can be derived there exist two pairs.

- `1` matches `bar`
- `2` matches `foo`
- `baz` doesn't have match

How can I query for src_a id `1` match? Expected result is src_b id `bar`. And from the other side. How can I query for src_b id `bar` match? Expected result is src_a id `1`.

Comment: Please include the result(s) you actually want. From all your words I still can't figure out what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that your problem can be solved w/o recursion by using a window function `row_number() over(<partition>)`. What you want is to find such pairs where the score is maximal for each id individually.

Given the sample dataset you provided - we can write this CTE where we have 2 row numbers (one for each id) and then sum them to get the rank of a pair:

```
with ranks as (
    select 
        src_a_id, 
        src_b_id, score,
        row_number() over (partition by src_b_id order by score desc) src_b_idx,
        row_number() over (partition by src_a_id order by score desc) 
            + row_number() over (partition by src_b_id order by score desc)  pair_rank
    from score
)
```

With that you'd get this result:

```
src_a_id  src_b_id  score   pair_rank
-------------------------------------
1         bar        0.7    3
1         baz        0.6    5
1         foo        0.8    3
2         bar        0.5    5
2         baz        0.8    3
2         foo        0.9    2
```

And now you can pick pairs where the `pair_rank` is minimal

```
select src_a_id, src_b_id, score from (
    select src_a_id, src_b_id, score, 
        row_number() over (partition by src_a_id order by pair_rank, src_b_idx) as index
    from ranks
) data where index = 1 and <CONDITION> (e.g. src_a_id = <YOUR ID>)
```

---

Given no  the query will result in all pairs where the score is the highest

```
src_a_id  src_b_id  score
-------------------------
1         bar       0.7
2         foo       0.9
```

---

EDIT:
There are several edge cases where the above approach yields ambiguous/incorrect result:

1. All pairs for a given `src_A_id` have lower score then any other pair sharing the same `src_B_id` (should the query return null/0 rows/highest amongst all `src_A_id`?)
2. Multiple pairs with the same highest score sharing `src_B_id` (which one wins over the other given the src_A_id are different?)
3. Multiple different `src_A_id` give the highest score for the same
   `src_B_id` (again, which one wins over the other given both src_A_id and src_B_id are the same?)

Given the below dataset, you can observe all 3 cases:

```
src_a_id src_b_id  score
------------------------
    1    foo       0.8  |
    1    bar       0.7  | -> all pairs are beanten by some other src_a_id
    1    baz       0.6  |
    2    foo       0.9
    2    bar       0.5
    2    baz       0.8  -> higest for `baz`, but 3.baz has the same score
    3    foo       0.91 |
    3    bar       0.91 | -> both pairs are the higest, but share src_a_id
    3    baz       0.8
```

And here is the adapted script, but you can adjust according to the desired behavior:

```
b_rank as (
    select 
        src_a_id, src_b_id,
        rank() over (partition by src_b_id order by score desc) src_b_idx
    from score
)

select src_a_id, src_b_id, score from (
    select 
        rank() over (partition by s.src_a_id order by score desc) score_rank, s.* 
    from score s
    join b_rank b on s.src_a_id = b.src_a_id and s.src_b_id = b.src_b_id and src_b_idx = 1
) data where score_rank = 1 and src_a_id = XXX
```

Which yield:

- `null` if all pairs are taken (example `src_a_id` = 1)
- the highest scored pair even if the same score is shared by another `src_b_id` (example `src_a_id` = 2)
- multiple rows if all these pairs have the highest score given the same `src_a_id` (example `src_a_id` = 3)

Comment: thank you for your answer. These features are new for me so it seems that will take some time to me to fully comprehend what is happening on the background. However for now I just copied your code to my scenario and it seems that it still returns the incorrect record. But I must put myself more into it and then I will let you know.

Comment: You can edit your answer with a sample dataset that gives you incorrect result and also what result you actually expect

Comment: I edited my answer. Using your query with condition for src_a_id = 1 it returns `foo` while I expect to get `bar`.

Comment: This is exactly what my query returns. Did you copy it correctly?
`where index = 1 and <CONDITION>` - the variable part here is the one in the angle brackets and the `index = 1` part should remain as-is.

Comment: I updated my question one more time and added your solution. Please review I use it correctly or review your query because currently the result of the query is `1` matches `foo`. You can verify it when you just run consequently create, insert and query.

Comment: @TomášVavřinka I updated the answer, but I still have a feeling that we deal with the [XY PROBLEM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) and not the real one

Comment: Thank you for great help. More I play with your query and searching on the internet the more I thing that I want query for something that can not by simply queried. According to my research my problem is called linear sum assignment (https://developers.google.com/optimization/assignment/linear_assignment). My `src_A` represents workers and `src_B` represents tasks. My scores represent costs. Only difference is that I want maximize costs and not minimize. Maximized cost is result I look for. One more time thank you for teaching me a lot of new stuff with Postgres.